# LibGDX Compare color of Box2D objects on collision

Tags: collision-detection, libgdx, box2d

I have two red balls and two yellow balls, which were created from a class Ball. 
The balls are box2d circles, with sprites attached.

Is there a way in which I can check to see if two balls have collided, and if they are the same colour, remove them?

I can access information about the bodies, but am not sure how to test whether they are the same colour.

I have the following code, but am not sure how to continue

```
@Override
        public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
            Fixture fixtureA = contact.getFixtureA();
            Fixture fixtureB = contact.getFixtureB();
```

Any ideas on what techniques I can use?

Regards

James